# CakePhp 2.0 .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.0

Having trouble configuring CakePhp on an Apache server. It worked fine in my dev environment, and now I'm looking to deploy.

The url will look like:

```
"http://www.example.com/mysite/"
```

A sample controller action would be:

```
"http://www.example.com/mysite/users/login"
```

Using the default htaccess files doesn't seem to work.

mod_rewrite is loaded according to phpInfo, and it is rewriting urls, but it sees /mysite/ as a controller. 
Here is the output and my .htaccess files

```
Missing Controller

Error: MysiteController could not be found.

Error: Create the class MysiteController below in file: >app/Controller/MysiteController.php
```

root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

app:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

webroot:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Should I be looking to change my .htaccess files, or my CakePhp config file? I've tried a few different RewriteBases, only managed to get different errors.

Edit: The server is running php-cgi and it appears all of my links are being written to a cgi-bin. For example:

```
$this->Html->meta('icon');
```

writes the path "/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/w3u_mysite/mysite/favicon.ico"
Any idea as to where or why this could be happening?

Comment: what's wrong with using the domain fully? (without the mysite part?) you can always use subdomains if you plan on using the domain for multiple apps.

Comment: That's the web space I was given by my host, I can't use the whole domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suspected in my edit, the problem was related to the server running cgi php. I'm not exactly sure what the issue was, but the CakePhp google group provided this solution:

In app/Config/core.php there is a commented out definition for App.baseUrl. Uncomment it and replace with the following

```
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', '/mysite/');
```

Above it, there are comments saying to remove the .htaccess files that you should ignore. The site worked fine with the .htaccess files as their standard values, no RewriteBase needed. The one annoyance was that `$this->Html->css()` and `$this->Html->js()` functions did not work, but I only call them in templates, so it's not terrible to hard code them.

If anyone has insight into the cause of these cgi woes, please share. It still feels a bit like a kludge if I can't use all of the Html helpers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to add `Rewritebase /mysite/` (possibly with '/mysite' quoted or without the second slash , you'll have to try) to your .htaccesses, so mod rewrite will take the folder in account.

---

Have you checked you `webroot/index.php` file for correct paths? 
As a last resort maybe filter out 'mysite' in the routes?

---

Final suggestion: prepend `mysite/` to `app` in your rewriterules.

Comment: All combinations of the first suggestion did not work, some made no difference, others produced an Internal Server Error.

I think the index.php is configured properly, but it is using the defaults. Customizing with the root path from phpInfo made no difference.

I attempted to alter the routing in CakePhp, and had interesting results. I believe the domain is using rewriting as well, as I was redirected to an alternate url with a CGI error.

The final suggestion resulted in an internal server error.

Comment: My host has specifically stated that AllowOverride for my directory is not set to All, but a directive. Could the RewriteBase not working as expected be a result of this?

Comment: I'm kinda out of suggestions here... There's one last question though, when you used RewriteBase, did you use it for all .htaccess files?

Comment: I tried both ways. It's strange that it is correctly routing to the controllers directory, but the css is not routed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issues with some servers.
Solution for me was to name the absolute path in all .htaccess files.

Something like:

root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule    ^$ /mysite/app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) /mysite/app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

app:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$    /mysite/app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) /mysite/app/webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

webroot:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mysite/app/webroot/index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```